# scaler fitting on two similar datasets produce different outcome

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, one-hot-encoding

I am using the test and training datasets from the following link:

https://www.kaggle.com/emrearslan123/house-price-prediction/data

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessin import StandardScaler
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')


important_num_cols = list(df.corr()["SalePrice"][(df.corr()["SalePrice"]>0.50) |   
          (df.corr()["SalePrice"]<-0.50)].index)

cat_cols = ["MSZoning", "Utilities","BldgType","Heating","KitchenQual","SaleCondition","LandSlope"]

important_cols = important_num_cols + cat_cols


df = df[important_cols]
important_cols.remove('SalePrice')
test = test[important_cols]

#the following lines correspond to na values in the test dataset 
#while df has no null values 

test['TotalBsmtSF'] = test['TotalBsmtSF'].fillna(test['TotalBsmtSF'].mode()[0])
test['GarageCars'] = test['GarageCars'].fillna(test['GarageCars'].mode()[0])
test['GarageArea'] = test['GarageArea'].fillna(test['GarageArea'].mean())
test['MSZoning'] = test['MSZoning'].fillna(test['MSZoning'].mode()[0])
test['Utilities'] = test['Utilities'].fillna(test['Utilities'].mode()[0])
test['KitchenQual'] = test['KitchenQual'].fillna(test['KitchenQual'].mode()[0])



y = df['SalePrice']
X = df.drop('SalePrice', axis=1)
```

So basically my training dataset X has the same number of features as my test dataset. However, when I apply one hot encoding pd.get_dummies on both datasets, my training data has 3 more features/columns than my test data.

```
X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=cat_cols)
test = pd.get_dummies(test, columns=cat_cols)
```

how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your categorical columns have different number of categories in train and test set, below we use `nunique()` to tell use the number of unique entries in each of your categorical columns:

```
import pandas as pd
train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

cat_cols = ["MSZoning", "Utilities","BldgType","Heating","KitchenQual",
"SaleCondition","LandSlope"]

train_df[cat_cols].nunique()

MSZoning         5
Utilities        2
BldgType         5
Heating          6
KitchenQual      4
SaleCondition    6
LandSlope        3

test_df[cat_cols].nunique()
MSZoning         5
Utilities        1
BldgType         5
Heating          4
KitchenQual      4
SaleCondition    6
LandSlope        3
```

What you can do is collect the categories for test and train, then make your columns categorical, specifying the categories explicitly:

```
categories = pd.concat([train_df,test_df])[cat_cols].dropna().apply(lambda x:x.unique())
for cat in cat_cols:
    train_df[cat] = pd.Categorical(train_df[cat],categories=categories[cat])
    test_df[cat] = pd.Categorical(test_df[cat],categories=categories[cat])
```

And:

```
pd.get_dummies(train_df[cat_cols]).shape
(1460, 31)

pd.get_dummies(test_df[cat_cols]).shape
(1459, 31)
```

Comment: when you say different number of categories do you mean columns or their values?

Comment: i mean the number of categories in each column, for example, Heating has 6 in train and only 4 in test